# How to show the logarithmic integral $Li(2)$ converges to a value?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals

The logarithmic integral is defined to be 
$$
\text{Li}(x) = \int_0^x \frac{dt}{\log t}.
$$
for $x\ne 1$, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function

I am trying to show that $\text{Li}(2)$ converges to a value.
Any comments would be appreciated. Thank you!

ps It got edited by someone else to be $\text{Li}(x)$ here, but in the Wikipedia page it is $\text{li}(x)$.

Comment: Bounded? You mean converges to a value?

Comment: Let me fix that

Comment: Are you familiar with principal value?

Comment: Yes, but somehow it wasn't working out...

Comment: Write the integral as
$$\int_0^x \left( \frac 1 {\ln t} - \frac 1 {t - 1} \right) dt +
 \operatorname {v.\!p.} \int_0^x \frac {dt} {t - 1}.$$